# Sketch 3 - Copied objects all changing when edited

Tags: sketch-app

I know this is a feature of Sketch but I don't know its name or how to shut it off.

I created a screen for an iOS app that has a base navigation bar at the bottom with symbols and text as the icons. I then created several other artboards by copying that one and pasting.

When I change the active state for the bottom nav, it changes the others which I don't want happening as I want to display each page with it's active nav.

What is the function called that links them together and how do I disable it or unlink the elements?

*EDIT* This seems to pertain mostly to shapes that I place via the insert menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called [symbols](https://www.sketchapp.com/support/documentation/07-symbols/).

If you want your elements to be unlinked from each other, right-click on one and select "detach from symbol" that group and all further copies will be able to be changed independently.

Comment: -Smacks Forehead- I was right clicking everywhere but not on the right level of the grouped items. Thank you for that info, has helped me immensely.